# TCL, Linux, and FLOCK

Tags: linux, tcl, flock

So I am working with a program written in TCL that uses the FLOCK function to lock files. I am testing it on a newer version of Linux than the one it currently runs on and I found that when the newer machine runs the script, it uses FLOCK from /usr/bin/flock, which differs from the TCL version of FLOCK. The TCL version uses -read -write and such, while the Linux version uses completely different options.

In short, the program stops working and errors out when it gets to any FLOCK call.  If I change the options to fit the Linux version, it breaks the program on the other machines.

Is there a way to make it use the TCL version as opposed to the Linux one?

Comment: All `FLOCK`-named things will go through either the kernel's `flock(2)` or `fcntl(2)` locking interfaces; `flock(2)` is advisory-only and does not work over NFS, so `fcntl(2)` was introduced to provide mandatory locks (rarely used) and over-NFS-locking. I suggest reading through the `flock(2)` manpage, especially the `NOTES` section, for the background that will probably help you better explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Hmm, well, the TCL script calls FLOCK with -write -nowait on files. This script normally runs on CentOS 5.7.  When it is run on Ubuntu 12.04, the FLOCK line fails with "invalid command name 'flock'".  If I change it to use FLOCK options in the Linux man pages, it will work on Ubuntu but fail on the CentOS 5.7 computers.

Answer (score 3):

Tcl itself does not come with a `flock` command, though you might be seeing it automatically trying to use the system command if you're testing interactively. Such automated use of system commands is *not done in scripts* (that would be hellishly prone to instability due to varying PATHs) so when writing a script you should be explicit as to what you mean.

If you want to use the system command (itself non-portable, especially to non-Linux systems) then just do:

```
exec flock $options...
```

Be aware that Tcl uses a different form of argument quoting to the shell. This can sometimes catch people out when writing `exec` calls.

**Alternatively,** use the [`flock`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2001) Tcl command that is in the [TclX package](http://tclx.sourceforge.net/). The syntax is a little different to that of the Linux system utility, in large part because it's a bit lower-level. In its favor, it is rather more portable.

Comment: Despite it's name, the `flock` command uses the fcntl(2) system API for locking. OTOH, if everything else that locks a file is using the system _command_ to do it, your script should do so too.

Comment: I just remembered to close this question by saying that installing the TclX package fixed this.  For some reason, without it, the TCL program would continuously error out when using FLOCK.